# Does this test make sense for testing concurrency problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency

I want to test that when a method is called from several threads, there is no concurrency problem. I simulate that the method is called 3 times simultaneously and insert 2000 customers in my cache in order to be sure there is no concurrency problem.

```
public void Should_Insert_2000_Customers_Using_Concurrency()
{
    var fakeCustomers = InitCustomersFromDb();
    Action insertCustomersFrom_0_to_1000 = new Action(() => 
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 1000, x =>
        {
            CustomerCache.Instance.SetCustomer(x.ToString(), fakeCustomers[0]);
        });

    });
    Action insertCustomersFrom_1000_to_2000 = new Action(() => 
    {
        Parallel.For(1000, 2000, x =>
        {
            CustomerCache.Instance.SetCustomer(x.ToString(), fakeCustomers[0]);
        });
    });
    Action insertCustomersFrom_0_to_2000 = new Action(() => 
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 2000, x =>
        {
            CustomerCache.Instance.SetCustomer(x.ToString(), fakeCustomers[0]);
        });
    });
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(insertCustomersFrom_0_to_1000));
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(insertCustomersFrom_1000_to_2000));
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(insertCustomersFrom_0_to_2000));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    var customers = CustomerCache.Instance.GetCustomers();
    Assert.That(customers.Count == 2000);
}
```

Will running multiple simultaneous `Parallel.For` iterations against my `CustomerCache` be effective at showing any concurrency problems?

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking for a code review?

Comment: I want to know if these kind of test are good to test multithreading. Or if it's useless...

Comment: Parallel.For is asynchrone, so you use many more threads depending on how many cpu's/cores you have.

Comment: I'd have thought it quite unlikely that the 3 loops inside your `Action`s will ever be working on the same id value at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is supposed to do. Why are you adding customers from 0..1000 and 1000..2000 and then overwriting them by adding from 0..2000.

Comment: Just to check behavior when setting the same key (to ensure not have an exception like when we add an existing key to a Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

IMO, this kind of test does not reveal much. Granted, for this particular case it's clear that the result will be correct at the end, but in a general case where you are inserting items in a collection concurrently it would be misleading to test for the number of items actually added, because getting what you expect does not exclude the possibility that there is a data race somewhere and that you just "got lucky".

Answer (score 1):

A test needs to test a particular scenario. A concurrency test needs to create a concurrency issue rather than hope one happens. The test should require a single run. If this is difficult in your code remember that there is a lot more functional code out there than testable code. But ... to reduce risk ... you want to make your code testable.

So, identify what you mean by 'concurrent' and make it happen. Be assertive. Call a method and mock what it is calling. When it calls something that tells you it is in the critical section then use the mocking framework to invoke another call.

Your now probably wondering "but that means multiple threads". Threads are a concept, inject the objects used to create the threads and anything that handles the conflicts.

You must be looking at a line or two and thinking .... "can two get to this". Test the guards.